# Spark: Avro schema information lost

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro

I am creating some Avro records and I am trying to convert them into another kind of Avro records. The creation of the records look like so

```scala
lazy val recordSchemaBuilder = SchemaBuilder.record("TypeA")
    .fields()
  
  recordSchemaBuilder.name("event").`type`(Event.SCHEMA$).noDefault()
  recordSchemaBuilder.name("user").`type`(User.SCHEMA$).noDefault()
  recordSchemaBuilder.name("dummy_asset_field_name").`type`.optional().`type`(AssetId.SCHEMA$)

  val recordSchema = recordSchemaBuilder.endRecord()

private def createTypeA() = {
    val recordBuilder = new GenericRecordBuilder(recordSchema)

    val event = Event.newBuilder()
      .build()

    val user = User.newBuilder()
      .build()

    recordBuilder.set("user", user)
      .set("event", event)
      .set("dummy_asset_field_name", AssetId.newBuilder().build())
    recordBuilder.build()
  }

test("One") {
    val df = createTypeA()
    convertToTypeB(df) match {
      case Right(opt) =>
        opt match {
          case Some(typeB) => println(s"TypeB event created $typeB")
          case None => println("No TypeB created")
        }
      case Left(bla) => //ignore
    }
  }

test("Two") {
    val typeAs = spark.sparkContext.parallelize {
      Seq(createTypeA())
    }
    
    typeAs.foreach(typeA => {
      convertToTypeB(typeA) match {
        case Right(opt) =>
          opt match {
            case Some(typeB) => println(s"TypeB event created $typeB")
            case None => println("No TypeB event created")
          }
        case Left(bla) =>
      }
    })
  }
```

This is part of the `convertToTypeB` method:

```scala
def convertToTypeB(record: GenericRecord): Either[Throwable, Option[TypeB]] = Try{
    val containsEvent = record.get("event") != null
    val eventIsInstanceOfEvent = record.get("event").isInstanceOf[Event]
    val containsUser = record.get("user") != null
    val userIsInstanceOfUser = record.get("user").isInstanceOf[User]
    val containsAllRequiredFields = (containsEvent && eventIsInstanceOfEvent) &&
      (containsUser && userIsInstanceOfUser) 

    if(containsAllRequiredFields){
       // Create type b event
       Some(typeBEvent)
    } else {
       None
    }
}.toEither
```

And now the question:

- In test `One` the boolean conditions in `convertToTypeB` evaluate to `true`
- In test `Two` the boolean conditions evaluating to true are `containsEvent` and `containsUser` while conditions `eventIsInstanceOfEvent` and `userIsInstanceOfUser` evaluate to `false`

Both tests are using the same method to create the test data, the only difference is that the second one is using a Spark context to create a data frame and is invoking the `convertToTypeB` while traversing this data frame. So my assumption is that somehow the Avro schema information and type are lost when I am creating the data frame using `spark.sparkContext.parallelize{...}`

Is this right? Why am I missing these info inside the Spark context.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but when the Avro `Seq` is mapped into a `RDD` it loses class information, it is converted into a `GenericRecord` - but it retains the schema information. Consequently, in the `convertToTypeB` method the `isInstanceOf` check is always invalid and has to be replaced with

```scala
record.get("event").asInstanceOf[GenericRecord].getSchema == Event.SCHEMA$
```

Once these checks are replaced, the conversion works as expected.